# Pass quiz score to Desire2Learn Valence via API

Tags: desire2learn

I am trying to integrate an external multimedia application with Valence.  The application presents the user with quizzes along the way, with each question mapping to a learning objective.  Using the API, how can I send the results of each quiz/objective to D2L so it's part of the overall course grade?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question, it's definitely a good one that I'd love to hear more about!

Right off the top, I'll say that unfortunately the short answer is that Valence currently doesn't support retrieving quiz information, nor accepting question responses to contribute to the user's quiz grade in the grade book, and competency-based evaluation.  We recognize this is a big gaping hole in Valence, but the reason why we don't have it yet is due to an assessment tools re-architecture which we're embarking on now, which will put things in place to expose more assessments tools functionality via Valence.

That said, I'd love to capture more details about your use case so that we @ D2L can be well-positioned to support it in the future.

1. Can I assume that you would want to perform the quiz create, update, delete operations, inclusive of learning objective question association, directly in D2L, and not via Valence?
2. Get Questions:  Would you be looking to retrieve all quiz question information, providing a quiz identifier?
3. Submit Responses, and Trigger Evaluation:  Would you be looking to submit all quiz question responses, in order to trigger automatic evaluation, to populate the quiz's score in the grade book, and contribute to competency-based evaluation?  Would you ever have a case where a question response was provided which required manual evaluation (such as a short/long answer question type)?  If so, how would you like to see that handled?

Many thanks again, I appreciate your time to communicate this request.